# Cannot sort columns in Gtk.TextView i Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

When I try to make my Gtk.TreeView in Python sortable by column I use something like

```
for i, column_title in enumerate(["Title A", "Title B"]):
    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
    column.set_sort_indicator(True)
    column.set_sort_order(Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)
    column.set_sort_column_id(i)  # trying to make columns sortable
    self.study_view.append_column(column)
```

but when I click on the title of a column I get the error message

```
(main.py:14540): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:46:43.573: gtk_tree_sortable_get_sort_column_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_SORTABLE (sortable)' failed
```

I've googled the problem but haven't found a solution. The docs give no hint. What's wrong?

Here's the line in the complete Python application the gives the error message:

https://github.com/nordlow/dicom/blob/master/main.py#L241

I'm using these docs as a reference:

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html?highlight=view#sorting

Comment: That is gtk3, not pyGtk. (Which is gtk2.)

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Are you saying there's another way of solving this in Gtk3 for Python. If so do you have a ref to the docs?

Comment: All I'm saying is that the `pygtk` tag was out of place. It's been a while since I've actually used gtk, so I'm afraid I can't help you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the more complicated pieces of machinery in Gtk. You need to wrap the filtered `TreeModel` with a sorted model, so that you can sort the filtered model again. Note that a plain `TreeModel` is sortable before you wrap it with a filtered model. So your code should look like this on line [225](https://github.com/nordlow/dicom/blob/8b68ca87e6b2efe1c330ae99315692c170c4327e/main.py#L225):

```
self.study_store = StudyStore(client=self.client)
self.current_study_filter = None
self.study_filter = self.study_store.filter_new()
self.study_filter.set_visible_func(self.study_view_filter_func)
self.study_sort = Gtk.TreeModelSort(self.study_filter)
self.study_view = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.study_sort)
```

P.S. I think you are overusing class variables. No offense please.